# What does "ascended to rule the heavens" mean?

Tags: meaning

Can you help me explain the meaning of the phrase *"ascend to rule the heavens on"* in the sentence below?

> *Myth was born in Thebes of Geb and Nut who **ascended to rule the heavens on** their death.*

Comment: When you ask questions here please check first for typos and other basic errors.

Comment: This has to do with Egyptian mythology; the sky goddess and the earth god mated and brought forth the gods Isis, Osiris and others. Thebes was an important city in Ancient Egypt. Basically, then, it is straightforward: "(Egyptian) myth was born in the city of Thebes with the story of Geb and Nut, who upon their deaths, went up to the heavens to rule."  (In actuality, Nut went to the heavens - she is the sky goddess among other things - and Geb stayed and became the earth god; they were separated by the sky god. Any good dictionary or two will give you the meanings.

Comment: Thanks for your useful information. Is it true that Nut only ascended to rule the heavens only when she died?

Comment: That is no longer English.

Comment: Do you mean that is no longer a question about English? OP is just asking for confirmation did Nut ascend to heaven only after she died. According to Egyptian myth as explained above----- yes.

Comment: @JackHunter Why did you reject my edit fixing your typos?!?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I asked for the confirmation to understanding the sentence meaning. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @curiousdannii: I wanted to edit myself. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Maybe because I fixed them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Egyptian mythology, [Nut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nut_%28goddess%29) was the sky goddess.  [Geb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geb), her twin brother and husband, was the god of Earth.

In the phrase *Geb and Nut who ascended to rule the heavens on their death*. The verb **ascend** means to *rise*, *climb (up)*, *go* (up), *scale*, and *fly*. It therefore makes sense that the most common nouns associated with *ascend* are the following: *the Father*, *H/heaven*, *throne*, and to a lesser extent; *top*, *summit*, and *God*. See Google [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ascended+to+heaven%2Cascended+to+Heaven%2Cascended+to+God%2Cascended+to+the+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=4&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cascended%20to%20heaven%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cascended%20to%20Heaven%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cascended%20to%20God%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cascended%20to%20the%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bascended%20to%20the%20top%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bascended%20to%20the%20summit%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bascended%20to%20the%20roof%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bascended%20to%20the%20throne%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bascended%20to%20the%20Father%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bascended%20to%20the%20upper%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bascended%20to%20the%20height%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bascended%20to%20the%20highest%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bascended%20to%20the%20right%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bascended%20to%20the%20drawing%3B%2Cc0).

Thus "who ascended to heaven" means someone who has either died or left Earth in order to reside in heaven (OR the heavens) i.e. the home of one or more deities. And in fact, the term **heaven** is derived from Old English *heofon* which means "home of God".

In Egyptian mythology:

> [Heaven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaven#Egypt) was a physical place far above the Earth in a "dark area" of space where there were no stars, basically **beyond the Universe**. According to the Book of the Dead, departed souls would undergo a literal journey to reach heaven, along the way to which there could exist hazards and other entities attempting to deny the reaching of heaven. Their heart would finally be weighed with the feather of truth, and if the sins weighed it down their heart was devoured.

Why did Thebes of Geb and Nut die and leave their terrestrial birthplace? In order **to rule the heavens**.

[image]

Comment: @medica very true, it was an oversight of mine.